# If URL is this: do this [..and include slug in page title?]

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

http://alexmasters.is/a/photographer

If you open one of the categories in a new tab/window (or go direct: http://alexmasters.is/shooting/weddings) you'll notice that the most recent entry's title is displaying in place of where Portfolio was, and where the category title should be.

Is it possible to use something like this:

```
<div id="page_title" class="page_title_portfolio border_bottom">
<h1 style="<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != '/shooting/'){echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">Cindy &#038; Akbar : </h1>
```

So that the /shooting/ category will trigger display:none; as a property of H1? And if that would work, would it also be possible to have the same conditional take what is after /shooting/ and use that in it's place?

Sort of like

```
<div id="page_title" class="page_title_portfolio border_bottom">
<h1 style="<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != '/shooting/'){echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">Cindy &#038; Akbar : </h1>
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != '/shooting/'){echo '<h1 style="{text-transform:capitalize;}">SLUG AFTER SHOOTING HERE</h1>'; } ?>">
```

^ This, obviously, because it's probably easier than trying to fix this:

```
<div id="page_title" class="page_title_portfolio border_bottom">
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<?php if (strlen(trim(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_page_extra_description', true))) > 0): ?>
<span>|</span> <p><?php echo trim(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_page_extra_description', true)); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't really understand what you're trying to tell us. With "If you open one of the categories in a new tab/window", do you mean 'headshots' or 'weddings' as the categories? If i open one of those in a new window or tab, it looks just fine. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @poepje - If you open headshots or weddings (or any one of the categories I'll be adding over time) then it displays the title (of the most recent entry, even though it shows ALL entries). The URL, however, contains the relevant title (after /shooting/). What I'm trying to do is have it hide the most recent title and drop in new code depending on what the category is. ie - the text after /shooting/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will grab current page url  and will make an array of uri items after http://alexmasters.is/ so for example if url is http://alexmasters.is/a/b/c you can print b like this echo $parts[1]; you can check if $parts[1] is empty so you can print $parts[0]

```
 <?php

function full_url()
{
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
    $protocol = substr(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), 0, strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/")) . $s;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
    $uri = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $segments = explode('?', $uri, 2);
    $url = $segments[0];
    return $url;
}

$uri = parse_url(full_url());

print_r($uri);
$parts = explode("/",substr($uri["path"],1));
print_r($parts);
echo $parts[0];
echo $parts[1];
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically and simply grab whatever text is after 'shooting' and format it? The first line gives me the impression that with every category I add, I'll have to edit the page in order to have it display the correct title. What I want is to hide the current title (ie Cindy & Akbar) and dislpay the text in the URL after /shooting/ (ie weddings). So, I suppose, for php to acknowledge the address as http://alexmasters.is/shooting/weddings, and then cut out http://alexmasters.is/shooting/ and only display weddings

Comment: try this code this will auto grab and remove  alexmasters.is/ and then you can ignore $parts[0] and always print $parts[1]

Comment: Thanks :D Sorted the first part with if url = /a/photographer then echo title else echo parts[1]